# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that every community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: mon]
[image: mon]
[image: mon]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them and appreciate the hard work and time they will contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are many members here who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, moderators should elected by the community, and that's why we'll hold elections once the site graduates.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

Let's also thank these users for having previously stepped up to moderate this community:

[image: mon]
[image: mon]

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for giving me the opportunity to serve as a moderator. Stack Exchange will play a large role in educating both users and developers of Monero as our network scales in the years to come. My goal is to make Stack Exchange as useful as possible and continually expand its reach.

I encourage everyone to get involved in meta discussions. Moderators do not make decisions in a vacuum. We value input from the Monero community.

Answer (score 4):

While my moderation appointment was somewhat of a surprise and I am relatively new to SE, I am a quick learner and feel up to the task.

Please use the `flag` option to call items to the attention of moderators and feel free to ask about any moderation actions you are curious about. Sometimes I may delay taking action and wait for others to review flagged items when I am undecided about the best course of action. Over time I hope to act as consistently as I can.

Comment: Not sure what the best way is to reach you. Could you create a chat user and ping me in the [Monero](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42720/monero) chat room here on Stack Exchange? :-)

Comment: yes, we can! my candidate did it, next step white house! :D *feelinglikerandymarsh*

Answer (score 3):

*Update 2018: Thanks for all the fish and [good luck](https://twitter.com/5chdn/status/1011922003945836544) with the community.*

---

Thank you for appointing me. :-)

I will focus on internal moderation tasks for now and help Smart Kid and 2quick 4u on additional tasks regarding external promotion of the site within the monero community and beyond.